# The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle and the 1D particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

This question and its answers, [Do linear momentum eigenstates exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/620872/does-linear-momentum-eigenstates-exist), very recently asked has me a bit stumped.

The OP basically states that the HUP:

$$\Delta x\cdot \Delta p\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}\tag{1}$$

implies that $p\neq 0$, always.

Or as one commenter ('Sebastian Riese') stated:

> The uncertainty conundrum is seen to be solved when looking at the
> approximations: The position uncertainty goes appropriately to
> infinity as we approach zero momentum uncertainty.

Now if we look at the very (teachable and) useful example of the $\text{1D}$ particle in a box with $\text{zero}$ potential energy $V(x)=0$ inside and infinitely high potential walls, we know that the ground state energy $E_1$ is non-$\text{zero}$, $E_1>0$.

Since as $V=0$, then:
$$E_1=V+K=K$$

This clearly implies that there is kinetic energy and thus motion and **momentum**, i.e. $p>0$.

Many, many moons ago I was taught (perhaps badly!) that this non-zero ground state energy is an illustration of the HUP, as it shows $p\neq 0$, in accordance with $(1)$. Because if $p=0$ then it is exactly known, so $\Delta p=0$, which violates the HUP.

And from this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335184/heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-applied-to-an-infinite-square-well):

> A simple way would be to realise that when $n=0$, the magnitude of the
> momentum is 0, and thus there are no 'positive' and 'negative' values
> it could take: it most definitely has a momentum of exactly zero, with
> no uncertainty. This would be allowed, if you were not in a box.
> However, placing yourself in a box, meaning that $Δx<∞$, means that you
> necessarily have a minimal non-zero momentum, using the argument you
> mentioned earlier.

That seems to confirm the role of HUP in explaining why non-zero ground energy is required.

Is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120899/discussion-on-question-by-gert-the-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-and-the-1d-p).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here is the thing: For a particle in a box, the **naïve** application of the HUP leads to an **apparent** contradiction. Here is the naïve properly formulated treatment:

> For the momentum operator $p:=-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx}$ the countable set of
> functions $\psi_n (x) :=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \exp\left(\pi i n x \right),~ n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
> form an orthonormal basis in the Hilbert space $L^2[-1,1]$.
> Pick any of the eigenvectors and you will find that $\Delta p=0$,
> thus, because $x$ in $L^2 [-1,1]$ is bounded and selfadjoint (therefore with a finite "uncertainty"), you are obliged to conclude that $\Delta x \Delta p =0$, apparently violating the HUP.

Is is a paradox? No, it is not. To render the momentum operator self-adjoint, you need to define its proper (maximal) domain as:

$$D(p) =\{\psi (x)\in L^2 [-1,1]~ \vert ~  \psi (-1) = \psi (1)\}.$$
Is is obvious that any eigenfunction $\psi_n $ of $p$ belongs to this domain and moreover $p~\psi_n \in D(p)$.

Now the trick is that for any $\psi (x)\in D(p)$, $x\psi (x) \notin D(p)$, therefore the commutator in the right hand side of the HUP is not defined, because the $px$ part of it does not exist as a linear operator.

So the HUP "survives" in the 1D infinite well, simply because the confinement (which accounts for the well-definiteness of momentum and ultimately Hamiltonian) precludes its application.

Comment: Relating to the original question of OP, the HUP is not what makes the ground state energy non-zero, right? Because the energy eigenstates are not even in the domain of definition of the commutator $[x,p]$.

Comment: It is trivial to show that the ground state energy can't be $0$, but this has nothing to do with the HUP, which could make statements only on the spectrum and eigenfunctions of the coordinate and momentum, if these two operators and their commutator is properly defined. In the well, as in general for no interaction, $H=\frac{P^2}{2m}$, but this squaring is tricky, because it involves unbounded operators, so if one draws conclusions from the HUP for $x$ and $p$, has to be careful to exend them to $H$ (spectrum and eigenfunctions).

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335184/heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-applied-to-an-infinite-square-well "*A simple way would be to realise that when n=0, the magnitude of the momentum is 0, and thus there are no 'positive' and 'negative' values it could take: it most definitely has a momentum of exactly zero, with no uncertainty. This would be allowed, if you were not in a box. However, placing yourself in a box, meaning that Δx<∞, means that you necessarily have a minimal non-zero momentum, using the argument you mentioned earlier.*" Seems to confirm my point about $p=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly tangential answer but I think it is relevant. In my experience, the assertion that a non-zero energy eigenvalue for the ground-state is associated with the HUP comes from the example of a simple harmonic oscillator much more naturally than from the case of a potential well. In the latter case, the domain of definition of the commutator does not include the energy eigenstates to begin with -- as explained in the wonderful answer by `@DanielC`. Also, see `@ACuriousMind`'s [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/233311/20427) to a similar question about the case of a particle on a ring.

In the case of the harmonic oscillator, however, this assertion seems to follow straightforwardly. We have
\begin{align}
H 
&=\frac{1}{2m}(p^2+m^2\omega^2x^2)\\
&=\frac{1}{2m}(p+im\omega x)(p-i\omega x) -\frac{i\omega}{2}[x,p]\\
&=\omega a^\dagger a -\frac{i\omega}{2}[x,p]
\end{align}
where the ladder operators have the usual meaning so that $a\vert 0\rangle=0$ and one can verify that such a $\vert 0\rangle$ exists (by just showing that there is a solution to the equation $a\vert\psi\rangle = 0$ where $a$ is the usual lowering operator).

Now, we see that $H\vert 0\rangle = -\frac{i\omega}{2}[x,p]\vert 0\rangle = \frac{\omega}{2}\vert 0\rangle$. In other words, the ground state energy being non-zero is synonymous with the commutator $[x,p]$ not being zero.

However, I think this is not as important as people make it out to be because a constant shift in the Hamiltonian is entirely meaningless in quantum mechanics. The same physical system can be described by the Hamiltonian $H=\omega a^\dagger a$ and then the energy eigenvalue for the ground state would be zero.

**Edit**

A constant shift in the energy is completely irrelevant for the simple reason because it amounts to the overall phase of the state which is known to be unphysical.

Let's consider a generic state $\vert \psi \rangle = \sum_n \vert E_n\rangle \langle E_n\vert \psi\rangle$. Now, its time evolution would be given by \begin{align}
\vert \psi(t)\rangle &= \sum_n e^{-iE_nt}\vert E_n\rangle \langle E_n\vert \psi\rangle\\
&= \sum_n e^{-i(\tilde{E}_n+E_0)t}\vert E_n\rangle \langle E_n\vert \psi\rangle\\
&= e^{-iE_0t}\sum_n e^{-i\tilde{E}_nt}\vert E_n\rangle \langle E_n\vert \psi\rangle
\end{align}

where $\tilde{E}_n\equiv E_n - E_0$ is the redefined energy. Thus, we see can always redefine the energy up to constant and it only adds to an overall phase -- not just in the case of energy eigenstates but also for a generic state.

Answer (score -2):

The topic of the *exact measure* is discussed in the [*Quantum Mechanics Feymann's Lectures on physics*](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_02.html#Ch2-S6) :

> [...] The question is whether the ideas of the exact position of a particle
> and the exact momentum of a particle are valid or not. The classical
> theory admits the ideas; the quantum theory does not. [...]

Thus, when you make a measurement the energy is not exactly defined, therefore, if you are in the case of the particle in a box, you cannot say *for sure* (when you make the measurement) that the particle is in the eigenstate with that energy eigenvalue.

Comment: The HUP applies even before measurement.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I'm generally baffled by David's comments and this answer but then I'm only a 'QM Lite'...

Comment: @Gert I really would like to know why are my comments wrong... If anybody knows it, please, comment...

Comment: Well, your comment in the last paragraph does not take into account the full QM (physical/interpretation) set-up which makes a distinction between preparation of a state and measurement on a state. In theory, if an observable has a purely point spectrum, you can prepare it in an eigenstate of it, therefore, accoring to Born's rule, upon measurement, it will return the same eigenvalue which was determined/imposed through preparation.